# Why Codeignitor does not accept autoload Controller classes when validating routes?

Tags: php, codeigniter, autoload

Why does Codeignitor not accept Controller in composer autoload when validating routes?

It's checking by: `class_exists($class, FALSE)` where the second parameter disables checking in autoload.

https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter

```
    $e404 = FALSE;
    $class = ucfirst($RTR->class);
    $method = $RTR->method;

    if (empty($class) OR ! file_exists(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$RTR->directory.$class.'.php'))
    {
        $e404 = TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        require_once(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$RTR->directory.$class.'.php');

        if ( ! class_exists($class, FALSE) OR $method[0] === '_' OR method_exists('CI_Controller', $method))
        {
            $e404 = TRUE;
        }
        elseif (method_exists($class, '_remap'))
        {
            $params = array($method, array_slice($URI->rsegments, 2));
            $method = '_remap';
        }
        elseif ( ! method_exists($class, $method))
        {
            $e404 = TRUE;
        }
        /**
         * DO NOT CHANGE THIS, NOTHING ELSE WORKS!
         *
         * - method_exists() returns true for non-public methods, which passes the previous elseif
         * - is_callable() returns false for PHP 4-style constructors, even if there's a __construct()
         * - method_exists($class, '__construct') won't work because CI_Controller::__construct() is inherited
         * - People will only complain if this doesn't work, even though it is documented that it shouldn't.
         *
         * ReflectionMethod::isConstructor() is the ONLY reliable check,
         * knowing which method will be executed as a constructor.
         */
        elseif ( ! is_callable(array($class, $method)))
        {
            $reflection = new ReflectionMethod($class, $method);
            if ( ! $reflection->isPublic() OR $reflection->isConstructor())
            {
                $e404 = TRUE;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking over the git history, the change was introduced in [49e68de96b420a444c826995746a5f09470e76d9](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/commit/49e68de96b420a444c826995746a5f09470e76d9), with the commit message being:

> Disable autoloader call from class_exists() occurences to improve performance
>
> Note: The Driver libary tests seem to depend on that, so one occurence in CI_Loader is left until we resolve that.

So the nominal reason is performance.

If you want to ensure that the controller classes will be loaded on each request, you can add the files explicitly to the Composer [`autoload.files`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#files) attribute, like so:

`composer.json`

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "src/Foo.php"
        ]
    },
    "name": "test/64166739"
}
```

`src/Foo.php`

```
<?php
class Foo {}
```

`test.php`

```
<?php
$loader = require('./vendor/autoload.php');
var_dump(class_exists('Foo', false));
```

When run (via `php test.php` for example), we get the following output:

```
bool(true)
```

#### Additional

Looking over the code around that call to `class_exists`, it would appear that the controller files should follow a convention such that, for example with the built in `Welcome` controller and the default settings, the file that defines it should exist at:

`application/controllers/Welcome.php`

and so after `require_once`ing that file, the call to `class_exists` is a reasonably simple sanity check to ensure that the file did in fact define that class. So, based on this assumption about how controllers are added to the CodeIgniter application (ie all in the `application/controllers` directory and named the same as the class that they define), it's reasonable to bypass the autoloader when performing that check.

If you wanted to ensure the controllers are loaded when needed, the CodeIgniter way, they should be added to the application as listed above.

Comment: It would be nice to also know in which way it improves performance.

Comment: Agreed :)
I suppose we could ask https://github.com/narfbg

Comment: This behavior makes it unable to detect my controllers which are declared with namespace, although i've already set config['composer_autoload']  = TRUE.
Is performance still ok when I remove checking file and change it to class_exists($class, TRUE)? my composer config is:
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
      "vendor/codeigniter/framework/system",
      "vendor/codeigniter/framework/application",
      "application/domain",
      "application/controllers"
    ]
  },

Comment: @NguyễnLouis in terms of the performance, you'll have to check with it autoload enabled and disabled to see whether there is any appreciable difference. With regards the namespacing, I'm fairly sure that CodeIgniter is not going to be able to load a namespaced controller. There isn't even really syntax to allow it from `routes.php`; using something like `$route['other-welcome'] = 'other/welcome/index'` simply tries to load the non-existent `Other` class, instead of the `Other\\Welcome` controller.

Comment: I realised that I hadn't really made it clear that all this is the case in CodeIgniter3 (which matches the code from the original question); it looks like in CodeIgniter4 the router can be configured to handle namespaced controller classes (though still within the `App\\Controllers` namespace).

Comment: I'm upgrading a CodeIgniter3 project to support namespaces controllers. Luckily, my change has worked :) I'll track it more for performance concern. Thank you for your helpful answer ;)